# Kotlin can't add to or remove from the Arraylist

Tags: android, class, kotlin, arraylist, fragment

Hello I have a class and there is a method in this class.The method creates random int values and I call my method in my fragment in while loop.The problem is I'm trying to add those values to an arrayList but It doesnt work(arrayList.Add code works in fragment in while loop but arrayList in class).I'm trying to add those values to an arrayList and use them in a textview in my fragment but It only returns default values.Here are my codes ;

MY CLASS;

```
open class Player {

//property
private var playerName : String
private var playerHealth : Int
var playerIsDead : Boolean = false
private var fragmentMetodDurumu : Boolean = ScreenFragment().fragmentMetodDurumu

//constructor
constructor(playerName:String,playerHealth:Int){
    this.playerName = playerName
    this.playerHealth = playerHealth
}

open var numberss: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(1,2,3,4)

fun attack(opponent : Player){
    //Create a random number between 1 and 10
    var damage = (1..10).random()

    //Subtract health points from the opponent
    opponent.determineHealth(damage)

    println(damage)
    Log.d("TAG-DAMAGE-WRITE","$damage")

    numberss.add(damage)
    Log.d("TAG-DAMAGE-ADD-TO-LIST","$numberss")

    Log.d("TAG-NUMBER-LIST-LATEST-VERSION","$numberss")
}


fun determineHealth(damageTaken:Int){
    if(this.playerHealth.minus(damageTaken) <= 0){
        this.playerHealth = 0
        this.playerIsDead = true
    }else{
        this.playerHealth = playerHealth.minus(damageTaken)
    }
}
```

}

MY FRAGMENT

```
class ScreenFragment : Fragment() {

var nickname : String? = null
var fragmentMetodDurumu : Boolean = false
private lateinit var viewModel : DenemeViewModel
lateinit var sonucListesi: MutableList<Int>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(DenemeViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.setData()

    arguments?.let {
        nickname = ScreenFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it).nickName
    }
    sFtextView.text = "Player : $nickname"
    olmasilazim()

}

private fun olmasilazim(){
    val health1 = (1..20).random()
    val health2 = (1..20).random()

    val superMan = Superman("Dusman",health1,)
    val batMan = Batman("Batman",health2)

    sonucListesi = Player("12312",1).numberss

    while(superMan.playerIsDead == false && batMan.playerIsDead == false){
        //attack each other
        superMan.attack(batMan)
        batMan.attack(superMan)

        fragmentMetodDurumu = true

        //see if anyone survived
        if(superMan.playerIsDead == true){
            sFtextsonuc.text = "Superman oldu"
            observeLiveData()
            fragmentMetodDurumu = false
        }
        if(batMan.playerIsDead == true){
            sFtextsonuc.text = "Batman oldu"
            observeLiveData()
            fragmentMetodDurumu = false
        }
    }
}

fun observeLiveData(){
    viewModel.damageList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { dmgList ->

        Log.d("TAGEA","$sonucListesi")

        dmgList?.let {
            sFtextsonuc.text = it.toString()
        }

    })
}
```

}

MY VIEWMODEL

```
class DenemeViewModel : ViewModel() {

val damageList:MutableLiveData<List<Int>> = MutableLiveData()

fun setData(){
    damageList.value = Player("",2).numberss
}
```

}

HERE LOGS

2022-03-31 15:16:53.200 17568-17568/com.korsdetek.oyundenemesi D/TAG-DAMAGE-WRITE: 9

2022-03-31 15:16:53.200 17568-17568/com.korsdetek.oyundenemesi D/TAG-DAMAGE-ADD-TO-LIST: [1, 2, 3, 4, 9]

2022-03-31 15:16:53.200 17568-17568/com.korsdetek.oyundenemesi D/TAG-NUMBER-LIST-LATEST-VERSION: [1, 2, 3, 4, 9]

2022-03-31 15:16:53.200 17568-17568/com.korsdetek.oyundenemesi D/TAG-DAMAGE-WRITE: 10

2022-03-31 15:16:53.200 17568-17568/com.korsdetek.oyundenemesi D/TAG-DAMAGE-ADD-TO-LIST: [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]

2022-03-31 15:16:53.200 17568-17568/com.korsdetek.oyundenemesi D/TAG-NUMBER-LIST-LATEST-VERSION: [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]

2022-03-31 15:16:53.203 17568-17568/com.korsdetek.oyundenemesi D/TAG-FRAGMENTE-ILETILEN-LISTE: [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: Did you try `open var numberss: MutableList<Int> = mutableArrayListOf(23,24,2,5)`

Comment: It says "Unresolved reference: mutableArrayListOf"

Comment: `mutableListOf`

Comment: I've used it and used again right now but still same

Comment: It is highly unusual that you keep calling the Player constructor only to grab a list from it and throw away the Player instance. It makes me wonder if you have a more fundamental OOP concept you still need to learn about before you can understand how to do this properly.

Comment: Or something like this is shocking: `var fragmentMetodDurumu : Boolean = ScreenFragment().fragmentMetodDurumu` You're creating a Fragment instance just to get the default value from one of its properties, which happens to simply be `false`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Actually I'm trying to learn it this is my first experience with oop and yes I deleted that one after I realize that one is not working because class doesn't notice the change of that boolean, I need to use livedata for that I guess

Comment: @Tenfour04 Actually I solved my problem with add and remove but I can't transfer my datalist to fragment and show in textview because It sends the default arraylist but in logs I can see the values added. Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with `sonucListesi = Player("12312",1).numberss` ? It doesn't make any sense to create a Player just to pull a list out of it and throw away the Player instance that the list belongs to. As an analogy, it would be like a window factory building a whole car, removing the window, throwing away the car, and shipping the window to the customer-- instead of just making a window and shipping it. It is also error prone to publicly expose mutable lists from classes because then it can be changed from both inside and outside the class. That could be your problem

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
open var numberss: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(1,2,3,4)

fun attack(){
    //removed some of the extra stuff in the function so I could test it faster
    var damage = (1..10).random()

    println(damage)

    numberss.add(damage)
    println(numberss)

    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Joe Pleavin , It adds the value to the list but then removes it and adds the new value then adds new value and previous value and next time removes every new value so It doesn'T work

Comment: Are you interacting anywhere else with the numberss array? That works perfectly fine on its own, for instance calling the above attack() function over and over just adds to a longer and longer list.

Comment: Yes I use numberss array in fragment so I did something like this to use it in fragment. sonucListesi = Player("12312",1).numberss

Comment: I think you need to edit the post to include the Player class. Something there seems to be resetting numberss as far as I'm understanding